# Create a projected vector off of XTS object

Tags: r, xts

I am working through an example that is presented in Excel and translating to R.  Essentially there is a time series which is used to create a model (projectX):

```
  # projectX :: float -> float
  projectX <- function(previousX){ ... }
```

Essentially the model is a function (projectX) that takes an input (a previous value of x) and returns an expected value of X.

I want to take the seed from the last value in my XTS and then use the value that generates as the seed to the next projection, and so forth ...N

```
 projectVector <- function(N, seed)
 {
     myX1 <- projectX(seed)
     myX2 <- projectX(myX1)
     myX3 <- projectX(myX2)
     myXN <- projectX(myXNMinusOne)

     c(myX1, myX2, myX3, myXN)
 }

 myProjection <- projectVector(last(myXTS)$x)
```

so this could be implemented like this:

```
# projectVector :: (integer, float) -> [float]
projectVector <- function(n, seed){

  results <- c(seed)
  previous <- seed
  for(i in 0:n){
    new <- projectX(previous)
    results[i+1] <- new
    previous <- new
  }
  results
}

projectVector(10, as.numeric(last(myXTS)$x))
```

I definitely feel there is a brute force solution.  However I feel that there is probably a more idiomatic and expressive way of achieving this in R.

Comment: Your example implementation of `projectVector` does not produce an xts object, and it's not clear what `projectX` returns (R doesn't have a float type... maybe you mean "double"?).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I added a type signature. You are right it doesn't produce an XTS object, is that the more idiomatic thing to do? My implementation of   projectVector (which I think leaves a lot to be desired) returns a vector/list/array (not sure what the right term is in R) of floats.